# How to prevent images from garbage collection?

Tags: python, tkinter, garbage-collection

All images are getting into garbage collection except the last one. How to show all images?

```
        t = 1
        images = []
        while t < total_t[0][0]:
            row = self.database.db_query(F"SELECT * FROM {self.database.main_table} where T_ID = {t}")
            
            t_type = row[0][1]
            t_kind = row[0][2]
            t_note = row[0][3]
            t_date = row[0][4]
            t_ammount = row[0][5]
            
            self.img = tk.PhotoImage(file=f"{transactions_path}{t-1}.png")
            
            images.append(self.img)
            
            t+=1
            
        for index, image in enumerate(images):
            self.image = image
            tk.Label(self.content_view_frame, image=self.image).grid(row=index)
```

Comment: You need to keep a reference to each image. You see the last one because a reference to that one is inside `self.image`. Change `images` to `self.images` and it should work.

Comment: @Pietro Thankyouu sooo much It worked.

Comment: @Pietro You can add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to each image. You see the last one because a reference to that one is inside `self.image`. Change `images` to `self.images` and it should work.

Cheers!